# Setting the lifetime of a refresh token for a converged app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-account

I'm working on a converged app ([see here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/09/04/working-with-the-converged-azure-ad-v2-app-model/)) where I'm using the OAuth2 flow, getting access + refresh token. I had a look at [configurable token lifetimes](https://github.com/reyk/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.md) however this looks like it's only applicable to custom AAD apps (not converged).

I wanted to understand a few things:

1. What's the lifetime of a refresh token (by default) for web authentication scenario, where we can safely store the tokens on the server?
2. Is there any way of changing the default lifetime?

Comment: I didn't test this. But I think it should be same as custom Applications.

Comment: To set the lifetime of a non-converged AAD only app, you'll sign in via PS modules and use the tenant Id. Do the converged apps have a shared tenant ID?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT - Did you see my comment?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) for information on what are the default token lifetimes and how to configure the lifetimes per tenant, or if you need - per app, using PowerShell.

Because the 'per app' settings apply to the *service principal* and not directly to the app object, it should not matter if the app is *v1* or *v2*